# How to create the count parameter for xls:number?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am creating a table via xsl-fo. So far it worked because the source xml would only contain one document resulting in one tables. I am currently switching to a source xml containing multiple documents. My xsl shall work with both types of sources. This is mostly working; only the table row  numbering with xsl:number doesn't.

My XSL:

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dxl="http://www.lotus.com/dxl"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:cpfo="http://www.compart.net/xmlns/cpfo">
    <xsl:param name="zeilenhoehe">
        4.3mm
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:decimal-format decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master
                    master-name="ErsteSeite" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm"
                    margin-left="25mm" margin-right="12.5mm" margin-top="10mm"
                    margin-bottom="12.5mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-bottom="54pt" />
                    <fo:region-after extent="54pt" />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:simple-page-master
                    master-name="FolgeSeite" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm"
                    margin-left="25mm" margin-right="12.5mm" margin-top="10mm"
                    margin-bottom="12.5mm">
                    <fo:region-body region-name="FolgeBody" margin-top="35mm" margin-bottom="54pt">
                    </fo:region-body>
                    <fo:region-before extent="25mm" region-name="FolgeKopfzeile" />
                    <fo:region-after extent="12mm" region-name="FolgeFußzeile" />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Seitenfolge">
                    <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="ErsteSeite" />
                    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="FolgeSeite"/>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>  
                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="FolgeSeiten">
                    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="FolgeSeite" />
                </fo:page-sequence-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <xsl:for-each select="//dxl:document">
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="FolgeSeiten">
                    <fo:flow flow-name="FolgeBody">
                        <xsl:if
                            test="dxl:item[@name='FLT']//dxl:text = 'ja' and dxl:item[@name='Mängeltexte']//dxl:text != ''">
                            <fo:block font-size="11pt" font-weight="bold" padding-before="5pt" padding-after="10pt">
                                Feststellungen, Hinweise,  Mängel
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:table display-align="center" font-size="8pt" border="0.5pt solid black">
                                <fo:table-column column-width="9mm" border-right="0.5pt solid black" />
                                <fo:table-column column-width="13mm" border-right="0.5pt solid black" />
                                <fo:table-header background-color="#E6E6E6" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell height="6mm" padding-start="1mm" padding-end="1mm">
                                            <fo:block>Pos.</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell height="6mm" padding-start="1mm" padding-end="1mm">
                                            <fo:block>Kennz.</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </fo:table-header>
                                <fo:table-body display-align="center">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="dxl:item[starts-with(@name, 'Pos_Leistungsart_')]">
                                        <xsl:param name="lfdnr" select="substring-after( @name , 'Pos_Leistungsart_')" />
                                        <xsl:if test="../dxl:item[@name=concat('Pos_Leistungsart_', $lfdnr)]//dxl:text = 'F'">
                                            <fo:table-row border-top="0.5pt solid black">
                                                <fo:table-cell height="6mm"
                                                    padding-start="1mm" padding-end="1mm">
                                                    <fo:block>
                                                        <xsl:number
                                                            count="//dxl:document[current()]/dxl:item[starts-with(@name, 'Pos_Leistungsart_') and dxl:textlist/dxl:text = 'F']" />
                                                    </fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:table-cell height="6mm"
                                                    padding-start="1mm" padding-end="1mm">
                                                    <fo:block>
                                                        <xsl:value-of
                                                            select="../dxl:item[@name=concat('Pos_Kennziffer_', $lfdnr)]//dxl:text" />
                                                    </fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                            </fo:table-row>
                                        </xsl:if>                                       
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </fo:table-body>
                            </fo:table>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My source, one document, working:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM 'xmlschemas/domino_9_0_1.dtd'>
<document xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' version='9.0' maintenanceversion='1.0'
 replicaid='C12571F000528D73' form='Prüfung'>
<item name='FLT'><textlist><text>ja</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Mängeltexte'><textlist><text>50$650101$65 Einspeisemessung$01 Allgemein$01 Beschichtung des Behälters beschädigt/ nicht wirksam$B - erheblicher Mangel$<break
/></text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_1'><textlist><text>D</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_1'><textlist><text>000001</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_2'><textlist><text>D</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_2'><textlist><text>000300</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_3'><textlist><text>D</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_3'><textlist><text>020407</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_4'><textlist><text>D</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_4'><textlist><text>020012</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_5'><textlist><text>F</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_5'><textlist><text>650101</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_6'><textlist><text>F</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_6'><textlist><text>123456</text></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Preis_6'><textlist><text/></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_7'><textlist><text/></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_7'><textlist><text/></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_8'><textlist><text/></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_8'><textlist><text/></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_9'><textlist><text/></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_9'><textlist><text/></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_10'><textlist><text/></textlist></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_10'><textlist><text/></textlist></item>
</document>
```

My source, multiple documents, numbering not working

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE database SYSTEM 'xmlschemas/domino_9_0_1.dtd'>
<database xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' version='9.0' maintenanceversion='1.0'
 replicaid='C12571F000528D73' path='di\anlsich\di_dg.nsf' title='Druckgeräte'
 templatename='DruckgeräteMaster' allowstoredforms='false' maintainunread='false'
 optimizetablebitmaps='true' increasemaxfields='true'>
<document form='Prüfung'>
<item name='FLT'><text>ja</text></item>
<item name='Mängeltexte'><text>40$100401$10 SCHUTZ VOR BRANDLASTEN$04 ABSTAND$01 ABSTAND ZU EINER GERINGEN BRANDLAST KLEINER ALS 5 M (AUSNAHME SIEHE UG 06)<break
/>Brandlast: Holzkiste mit Brennholz unmittelbar am FLT$H - geringfügiger Mangel$<break
/>50$010605$01 BEHÄLTERAUSRÜSTUNG - ALLGEMEIN$06 FARBANSTRICH - KORROSIONSSCHUTZ$05 VERSCHMUTZT$H - geringfügiger Mangel$<break
/>60$020207$02 BEHÄLTERAUSRÜSTUNG - SICHERHEITSTECHNISCHE EINRICHTUNGEN$02 MANOMETER$07 ANGEZEIGTER WERT AM BETRIEBSMANOMETER WEICHT ERHEBLICH AB$H - geringfügiger Mangel$<break
/>70$020306$02 BEHÄLTERAUSRÜSTUNG - SICHERHEITSTECHNISCHE EINRICHTUNGEN$03 SICHERHEITSVENTIL$06 ANSPRECHDRUCK UNTERHALB DER ZULÄSSIGEN TOLERANZ$B - erheblicher Mangel$<break
/></text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_1'><text>D</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_1'><text>000001</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_2'><text>D</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_2'><text>000001</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_3'><text>D</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_3'><text>000101</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_4'><text>F</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_4'><text>100401</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_5'><text>F</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_5'><text>010605</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_6'><text>F</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_6'><text>020207</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_7'><text>F</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_7'><text>020306</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_8'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_8'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_9'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_9'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_10'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_10'><text/></item>
</document>
<document form='Prüfung'>
<item name='FLT'><text>ja</text></item>
<item name='Mängeltexte'><text>30$010605$01 BEHÄLTERAUSRÜSTUNG - ALLGEMEIN$06 FARBANSTRICH - KORROSIONSSCHUTZ$05 VERSCHMUTZT<break
/>Verschmutzt, Reinigung erforderlich$H - geringfügiger Mangel$<break/>40$080104$08 ZUGÄNGLICHKEIT$01 AUFSTELLUNG IM FREIEN$04 ABSTAND DER ÖFFNUNGSLOSEN SEITE DES BEHÄLTERS ZU ZAUN - STRAUCH - GEBÄUDEWAND - SCHUTZWAND KLEINER ALS 0.5 M<break
/>Abstand der öffnungslosen Seiten des Behälters zu Zaun, Strauch, Gebäudewand, Schutzwand &lt;0,5m, Sträucher um und unter dem Behälter freischneiden.$H - geringfügiger Mangel$<break
/></text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_1'><text>D</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_1'><text>000001</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_2'><text>D</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_2'><text>000005</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_3'><text>F</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_3'><text>010605</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_4'><text>F</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_4'><text>080104</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_5'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_5'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_6'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_6'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_7'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_7'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_8'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_8'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_9'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_9'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_10'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_10'><text/></item>
</document>
<document form='Prüfung'>
<item name='FLT'><text>ja</text></item>
<item name='Mängeltexte'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_1'><text>D</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_1'><text>000001</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_2'><text>D</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_2'><text>000300</text></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_3'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_3'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_4'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_4'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_5'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_5'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_6'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_6'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_7'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_7'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_8'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_8'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_9'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_9'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Leistungsart_10'><text/></item>
<item name='Pos_Kennziffer_10'><text/></item>

</document>
</database>
```

I tried to change the "count" parameter to `../dxl:item[...]`, but that is not allowed with count. I also tried to move the table row generation to a `<xsl:template select="//dxl:document>` so that the Pos_Leistungsart_* items would be in the descendant axis, but I think the processor didn't even call the template.
Is there a way to number the table rows?

Comment: I suggest you cut all samples to the minimum to demonstrate that particular problem, then also include the current output you get and the one you want instead.

Comment: Please reduce the examples to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current call on xsl:number appears to be

```
<xsl:number count="//dxl:document[current()]/dxl:item[
                starts-with(@name, 'Pos_Leistungsart_') 
                  and dxl:textlist/dxl:text = 'F']" />
```

Now, that doesn't actually make much sense. The value of `count` is a pattern, and a `//` at the start of a pattern makes no difference to the nodes it matches. Further the predicate `[current()]` makes no sense - it will be true if there is a context item, which there is. All your `dxl:item` elements are children of a `dxl:document`, so as far as I can see, you could simply leave out the `//dxl:document[current()]/` at the start of the pattern.

The significant difference in your second XML isn't that the `document` elements are now children of a `database` element; rather, the significant factor seems to be that the `text` elements are no longer wrapped in a `textlist` element, while the `count` pattern explicitly counts only those items where `dxl:textlist/dxl:text = 'F'`.

Comment: The working count attribute is `dxl:item[starts-with(@name, 'Pos_Leistungsart_') and .//dxl:text = 'F']`. Having not taken into account that there is or isn't a `dxl:textlist` is a bit embarrassing, because I `select` `dxl:item[...]//dxl:text` all over the xsl.